# How can I convert HTML to XPS?

Tags: html, image, xps

How can I convert HTML to XPS?

---

Need a way or a library.
But not the finished software product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print page from browser to **Microsoft XPS Document Writer** (Virual Printer).